Один файл имеет разные даты и содержимое в проводнике Windows и far. Что это может быть
. В Far Manager и проводнике windows один и тот же файл rxStrUtils.pas имеет разные даты. Это я бы пережил, но при просмотре в них находится не одинаковый текст. В Far тот, в который я вносил изменение, а в проводнике - исходный (смотрел в Notepad). Изменения вносились через IDE Delphi7. Более того, если я копирую файл в другой каталог с помощью Far, то копируется измененный текст, а если с помощью проводника - то исходный. Такое впечатление, что в одном и том же каталоге под одним и тем же именем хранятся разные файлы. Что невозможно. Никогда не сталкивался с подобной ситуацией. Хотелось бы услышать версии причин подобной ситуации и способов борьбы с ней. Спасибо.

Вероятно, вы смотрите на разные директории, но по картинке этого точно не скажешь. Кроме того, Delphi 7 следует устанавливать в каталог, путь к которому не содержит длинных имён и пробелов, например, D:\Delphi7\, иначе всякие чудеса могут случиться.

@MBo в заголовках обоих окон есть полный путь

Какая версия Far?

@andreymal 1.x у него версия, притом неактивированная

@andreymal Да, действительно. Но совет про каталог Delphi остаётся в силе.

А что на этот счёт думает команда DIR? И сколько файлов с таким именем она найдёт, если натравить её на весь диск?

@PavelMayorov ну вот слово Shareware навело меня на мысль, что автор вопроса запускает какое-то древнее зло, которое винда запускает в песочнице и изменения в котором сохраняются не по оригинальному пути (на изменение которого нужны права администратора, которые древнее зло запрашивать тупо не умеет), а где-то внутри AppData

@andreymal да, у меня та же мысль возникла

"Изменения вносились через IDE Delphi7." - это наталкивает на мысль, что Delphi запускалось в режиме виртуализации файловой системы и вместо недоступных для записи файлов в папке Program Files изменения попадали в %LOCAL­APP­DATA%\Virtual­Store

Вы напоролись на явление под названием "User Account Control Data Redirection".
Эта штука работает со старыми программами ("старость" определяется исходя из наличия т.н. манифеста) и перенаправляет запись в файлы, к которым нет доступа, в отдельную папку - обычно это C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore. Или, более коротко, %LOCALAPP­DATA%\Virtual­Store.
В вашем случае, и Delphi 7, и Far Manager оказались "старыми" - а потому они видят файлы, отредактированные друг другом. Проводник же - "новый" (ещё бы), и он эти изменения не видит.
Выйти из этого положения можно несколькими способами:

Ничего не делать. Нет ничего плохого в том, что редактируемые вами файлы видны только вам- ради этого всё и затевалось. Delphi и Far Manager отлично видят друг друга, а Проводник не нужен. Ну и, если вам нужен Проводник, вы всегда можете открыть %LOCAL­APP­DATA%\Virtual­Store в нём напрямую.

Запустить Delphi или Far Manager с правами администратора, если вам зачем-то нужно внести изменения для всех пользователей.

Настроить права на файлы, чтобы их могли редактировать все пользователи (но зачем?).

Поставить современный Far Manager (тогда он перестанет видеть то, что видит Delphi, а станет видеть то, что видит Проводник)

Поставить Delphi в другую папку, и дать доступ всем пользователям (но зачем?)

Отключить UAC



Оказывается, можно через диспетчер задач ткнуть галочку «Виртуализация UAC» на explorer.exe — и Проводник тоже начинает видеть изменения

Спасибо. Исчерпывающее разъяснение. Когда-то я проспал UAC. Правда активно программированием уже лет 15 не занимаюсь - мелочи для себя иногда делаю. Вопрос закрыт.
